# Bounding $\int_0^1 f(x) dx $ under the condition $\int_0^1 f'(x)^2 dx \le 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Any tips on how to solve this?

> **Problem 1.1.28 (Fa87)** Let $S$ be the set of all real $C^1$ functions $f$ on $[0, 1]$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and
>
> $$\int_0^1 f'(x)^2 dx \le 1 \;. $$
>
> Define
>
> $$J(f) = \int_0^1 f(x) dx \; .$$
>
> Show that the function $J$ is bounded on $S$, and compute its supremum. Is there a function $f_0 \in S$ at which $J$ attains its maximum value? If so, what is $f_0$?

I tried using Cauchy-Schwartz and got a bound of $\frac23$ but it doesn't seem strong enough.

Comment: Is $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$?

Comment: $f$ is continuous and thus maps every compact set to a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I don't think so,it's probably [0,1]→R

Comment: Why does the bound of 2/3 not seem strong enough? It seems to come from Cauchy-Schwarz that $|J(f)|\leq 2/3$.

Comment: @Moya which function do you mean?

Comment: Never mind, forgot $f(0)=0$

Comment: But f(0)=2/3 then so it's not in S

Comment: @M.Kar The quality of this image is seriously hurting my eyes :(

Answer (score 19):

A try for a solution:

We have by integration by parts: 
$$J(f)=\int_0^1 (1-t)f^{\prime}(t)dt$$
and Cauchy-Schwarz gives that $|J(f)|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.
Let $f_0(x)=\sqrt{3}(x-\frac{x^2}{2})$. Then $f_0^{\prime}(x)=\sqrt{3}(1-x)$, and $\int_0^1 f_0^{\prime}(t)^2 dt=1$. We have $J(f_0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, and we are done.

Answer (score 8):

Another way for proving the upper bound is the following. We have, using Cauchy-Schwarz twice, that $$\begin{align}
\left|\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx\right|= & \left|\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}f'\left(t\right)dtdx\right| \\
\leq & \left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{x}f'\left(t\right)dt\right)^{2}dx\right)^{1/2} \\ \leq & \left(\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}\int_{0}^{x}f'^{2}\left(t\right)dtdx\right)^{1/2} \\
\leq & \left(\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}dx\right)^{1/2} \\ = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: There can't be others. Once you have the functional represented in terms of its Riesz representation, $Jf = (f',1-t)$, you have max iff $f'=C(1-t)$, where $C(1-t,1-t)$ is positive, and $C^2(1-t,1-t)=1$.

Comment: @TrialAndError Yes I see now, thank you :)